# How to add two data frames together in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, sum, rows

I have a data frame delineated by ownership, private(50) and state(30). Looking to create 5 new rows that are the sum of ownership 50 and ownership 30 as long as they have a matching area value. Desired result is below.

```
naics  <- c(611,611,611,611,611,611,611,611,611,611)
ownership <- c(50,50,50,50,50,30,30,30,30,10)
area <- c(001,003,005,009,011,001,003,005,011,001)
d200201 <- c(14,17,20,23,26,3,5,7,9,100)
d200202 <- c(15,18,21,24,28,9,11,13,15,105)

private <- data.frame(naics,ownership,area,d200201,d200202)

naics    ownership     area     d200201     d200202
 611         50          001       17          24
 611         50          003       22          29
 611         50          005       27          34
 611         50          009       23          24  (no sum because no 30 value)
 611         50          011       35          43
```

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
library(dplyr)

private %>% 
  group_by(naics, area) %>% 
  summarize(
    across(c(d200201, d200202), ~sum(.x[ownership %in% c(30, 50)])), 
    ownership = 50, .groups = "drop"
  )
```

Output

```
# A tibble: 5 x 5
  naics  area d200201 d200202 ownership
  <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>
1   611     1      17      24        50
2   611     3      22      29        50
3   611     5      27      34        50
4   611     9      23      24        50
5   611    11      35      43        50
```

Comment: This is more elegant than the approach I was taking as a response. Still noodling over `~sum(.x[ownership %in% c(30, 50)])` in the summarize..across construction.

Answer (score 1):

```r
library(tidyverse)

private %>%
  filter(ownership %in% c(50, 30)) %>%
  group_by(area) %>%
  summarize(across(starts_with("d200"), sum))
#> # A tibble: 5 × 3
#>    area d200201 d200202
#>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1     1      17      24
#> 2     3      22      29
#> 3     5      27      34
#> 4     9      23      24
#> 5    11      35      43
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>